# Why the loop stops before it's end?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string();
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++ )
    {
         //printf("%c\n",name[i]);
         if(name[i]=='\0' && name[i+1]!='\0') //try to print the next char of space
        {   
            if(name[i+1]<='z' && name[i+1]>='a')
            {
                printf("%c",name[i+1]);
            }
            if(name[i+1]<='Z' && name[i+1]>'A')
            {
                printf("%c",name[i+1]);
            }
        }
        else;
    }
}
```

get_string() is to get users input as a string.

After I run this, it only print the first char that I input,which means the loop stops.

Is there anything wrong with my conditon lines?

---

after I change `for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++ )`  to `for(int i=0;i<strlen(name)-1;i++ )`,it gives me a Segmentation fault. I will look into it more.

Comment: You are assigning null

Comment: Many things wrong. First of all, you hard code the character codes.

Comment: after I  change   "for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++ ) " to " for(int i=0;i<strlen(name)-1;i++ )",it gives me a Segmentation fault. I will look into it more.

Comment: `name>'A'`? Please enable compiler warnings, and follow up on them.

Comment: ok , this qeustion is really stupid....

Answer (score 0):

Now I know why.

I thought `'\0'` equals `' '` ,and they are both the end of a string and space,which is very wrong.

All because of my bad english. I learnt it wrong from very begaining.

Stupid question.But I don't want to delete it,since maybe someone like me can use it.

This is my final answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

void caps(char x);

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string();
if (name!=NULL){
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
    {
       //  printf("%c\n",name[i]);
        if(i==0&&name[0]!=0)
        {
            caps(name[0]);
        }
        if(name[i]==' '&& name[i+1]!=' ') //try to print the next character
        {  
            caps(name[i+1]);
        }
    }
  }
}

void caps(char x)
{
    if(x<='z' && x>='a')
        {
            printf("%c",x-('a'-'A'));
        }
    if(x>='A' && x<='Z')
        {
            printf("%c",x);
        }

}
```

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with `' '`. It is because you apparently still haven't learned the difference between `=` and `==` in C. Don't mix the two.

Comment: I was not careful enough. I acaully know == is a comparing and = is to give the right things to the left.